# What is $K_2(\mathbb{Z}[x,x^{-1}])$?

Tags: kt.k-theory-and-homology, algebraic-k-theory

The question is as in the title: is $K_2(\mathbb{Z}[x,x^{-1}])$ known?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Bass/Quillen's Fundamental Theorem of Algebraic K-theory gives:
$$K_n(R[x,x^{-1}])=K_n(R)\oplus K_{n-1}(R)\oplus NK_n(R)\oplus NK_n(R)$$
where the two identical nil-terms vanish for $R$ regular.

Because ${\mathbb Z}$ is regular, this gives
$$K_2({\mathbb Z}[x,x^{-1}])
=K_2({\mathbb Z})\oplus K_1({\mathbb Z}) 
\approx 
{\mathbb Z}/2{\mathbb Z}\oplus {\mathbb Z}/2{\mathbb Z}$$